# Having trouble listing AdminDirectory groups in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get groups in Google Apps Script.  My code is as follows:

```
var list = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({
    customer: 'my_customer'
});
```

I tried the above, and I tried replacing the customer arg with domain: MYDOMAIN (and I tried with a userKey) but I always get the same error:

**Executing query for datasource SearchResults: (Error) : We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. [18a249eb]**

Is this not the right way to get the groups?  (Incidentally, I would ideally like to search for groups rather than listing them all, but I don't see that as an option.)

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Comment: Is this for your domain or a customers domain?

Comment: It is for my own domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Using the debugger and breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#common_errors), this error can be one of the following:

Server error occurred, please try again.
There are a couple possible causes for this error:

> 1. A Google server or system is temporarily unavailable. Wait for a few moments and try running the script again.
> 2. There is an error in your script that doesn't have a corresponding error message. Try debugging your script and see if you can isolate
>      the problem.
> 3. There is a bug in Google Apps Script that is causing this error. Report the error on the issue tracker.

Make sure you're following the [List all groups](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) guide correctly:

```
function listAllGroups() {
  var pageToken, page;
  do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({
      domain: 'example.com',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var groups = page.groups;
    if (groups) {
      for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        var group = groups[i];
        Logger.log('%s (%s)', group.name, group.email);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('No groups found.');
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
}
```